# Javascript error XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Im currently working on an online-shop(System is Gambio) and I got Pop-Up images in a lightbox. But it doesn't work when Im trying to open the pictures.

In Chrome console I got the error messages:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://zoobedarfxxl.de/request_port.php?module=Attributes&action=attribute_images&options_ids=&values_ids=.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin  is therefore not allowed access.

and

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   h.ttp://zoobedarfxxl.de/request_port.php?module=LightboxGallery&id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63ec1814f33dccf6af1c422c1f4.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.

and

```
VM5415:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefinedButtonProductImagesHandler.gallery_init_binds
@ VM5415:1(anonymous function) @ VM5415:1n.extend.each 
@ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:8n.fn.n.each @ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:8(anonymous function) 
@ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:10j @ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:8k.fireWith 
@ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:8x @ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:10b 
@ gm_javascript.js.php?cPath=8577&products_id=15066&XTCsid=565bb63…&XTCsid_na…:10
```

I searched the problem a little bit, but I was not able to figure how to solve the problem. Has anyone some Hints oder Ideas how to solve this?

Greetings
Tim

Comment: may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue. Have a look on StackOverflow questions with CORS tag.

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests
>   initiated from within scripts.

There are restrictions while making ajax request to the server other than the document's domain.

The reason of error is "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`" header is not supplied by other server.

Resources:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS